# jQuery Cycle - pager spilt into multiple divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am using the jQuery Cycle Plugin to create a slideshow, however I want to be able to pagnate the thumbnails into multiple divs. At the moment they are all placed into one div - #right .thumbs.

I would like the following:

> Image 1-25 - div.thumbs
>
> Image 26-50 - div.thumbs
>
> etc

Instead of

> Image 1-50 - div.thumbs

Let me know if that doesn't make sense. Here is the code I'm currently using ...

```
$('#left .slides').cycle({
        timeout:0,
        speed:1200,
        fx:'fade',
        pager: '#right .thumbs',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            img = $('#'+slide.id).find('img').attr('src');
            return "<li style='background-image:url("+img+")'><a href='#'></a></li>"; 
        } 
});
```